# Excel 2016 Text to columns 255 character limit

Tags: microsoft-excel

While importing a csv into excel there is a column of data that occasionally has more than 255 characters in it.  When running the text to column command, it truncates these cells to 255 characters.  Is there  way to get around this in excel 2016?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  I have no problem with importing csv files that contain more than 255 characters in a field.  Please supply more detail as to what is going on?

Comment: Try  this string. It is a sample of one of the columns. 
Only the commas are being split. 
 After the split you can see the length is 255 characters.  It should be 374.  
 'asdf,-21|204;2.25;23|-189;1;-47|66;0.5;33|-128;1.25;-26|284;2;36|-212;2.25;-24|72;0.25;72|-60;0.75;-20|115;2.25;13|-171;3;-14|93;1.25;19|-51;1.25;-10|152;1;38|-132;1.25;-26|62;0.75;21|-561;1;-140|61;0.75;20|-156;0.5;-78|101;1.25;20|-319;1.75;-46|118;1.25;24|-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string, which when I copy/paste it, is only 281 characters.  So I would expect it to split into two strings of 5 and 275 characters.

However, there is something strange about that string, and it seems to cause the old Text-to-Columns wizard to truncate it to 255 characters.  At first I thought it might be related to the various Unicode characters `ZWSP` and `ZWNJ` scattered here and there.  But replacing them with spaces still resulted in the same truncation.

Other ASCII text strings can be split on the comma even with lengths much greater than 255.  Possibly a bug?

However, in Excel 2016, you can use the column splitting tool accessed from the `Get & Transform` tab on the `Data` ribbon. If you have updated your version (eg via Office 365) this may open when you double click on a CSV file.  If it does not, open your file using the `From Text/CSV` selection of `Get & Transform Data`.  Follow the prompts (it should show a Unicode type of file), and select comma for the column split.  Doing that, it splits correctly.

Also, if you can import the csv row into a single row (unsplit) in Excel, you can use the `From Table/Range` option on `Get & Transform` to navigate to the column split command that will work.

**EDIT:** Further investigation into this reveals the bug seems to be triggered if the first character of the segment following the comma is a plus (+), minus (-) or equal (=) sign.

It turns out that another workaround for the bug is to specify that the column be classified as **TEXT** (step 3 of the wizard).  This may be useful for those with older versions of Excel.

Comment: The split column command was what I needed to use.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. It is the limitation of the "column width" as specified in the spec: [Excel 2016 limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Your best bet would be to split the content prior to import using some type of script. i.e. python. Plenty of example on Stack overflow like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111068/split-string-by-count-of-characters

Comment: That limit is for the column width. This is **NOT** the same as the number of characters in a cell.  Which is something like 32,767

Comment: I think it depends how it's imported

Comment: How would you import it in Excel 2016 and have the cell contents limited to 255 characters?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue while exporting from SSIS ,it will automatically truncate with 255 character.

### Root Cause

Excel automatically assign column length limit by considering first 8 consecutive rows.So if a column have more than 255 character then excel will took that length otherwise the default 255 will be allowed.

### To Fix

I added 4000 characters in columns on 2nd row and hide that row.So excel will took the column length as 4000.

Answer (score 0):

`raveeshvn` is correct.

The default for Excel when importing (and the Text to Columns functionality is the direct offspring of the Import Wizard, so... "importing" by any other name still smells sweet...), is to look at the first 8 rows for each column and decide how to not only bring the data in (can you say "HEY! Where did my leading 0's go in this column?" or "HEY! That column isn't dates, why is Excel importing it as dates?"), but how to format it for display after bringing it in.

You periodically see people upset that an imported column of time values turns out to be formatted as minutes:seconds rather than hours:minutes:seconds. "Turns out" meaning they never checked the formatting, or data lower down in the CSV (yet... still excoriate Excel for only looking at 8 rows when they looked at the first one, two, or maybe three, and not in much detail). Well duh, the 30,000 rows of data came sorted so the first thousand or two rows had only minutes and seconds, with hours not appearing until maybe row 1,377.

All part and parcel of this issue.

You CAN force Excel to look at however many rows you wish, but it does so then for all columns, and some imports have hundreds of columns, so looking at 2,000 rows to catch that time issue (which is solved with a simple format change usually), might mean examining half a million rows before the import proceeds.

Another approach is to do what `raveshvn` does, inserting at least one example row forcing Excel to be aware of a column having a broader range of data. Delete it after opening the file.

As to the actual T2C functionality, it has no issue whatsoever with producing columns whose content exceeds 255 characters. I've done this for decades and never have had difficulties and I just did it again with the string from a comment. Deleted its comma and put one in after the first character. Excel happily provided me 257 characters in the second column.

There ARE functions, like `VLOOKUP()` that are limited in this manner. And many programs that export CSV's knowing they are intended for use in Excel limit their exported fields to 255 characters, creating as many columns as necessary to export the entire fields (and so the many, many import files that have hundreds of columns...). Them doing so is absolutely not the same thing as Excel limiting column content length to 255 characters!

The following string has 4,001 characters, the second being a comma. T2C produces a single character cell and a 3,999 character cell next to it:

a,bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|

Extend that string to 36,000 characters and as expected, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> causes Excel to commit the entry and truncate it at 32,767 characters according to `LEN()`. Editing to remove the last character and placing a comma as the second character works nicely. The T2C splits it:  a 1 character cell and a 32,759 character cell. Interestingly, six characters are lost (the comma goes away as a delimiter leaving 32,766 characters minus the 1 in the left cell and the 32,759 in the right cell so six characters lost in the shuffle. But... not 32,000+ lost.

Other workarounds exist for imports, like renaming the CSV to TXT, then importing. But that is more of a workaround for being able to tell Excel what kind of data is in a column rather than Excel importing without asking questions and leaving you a mess. This is not precisely that so... The only really great one is Power Query as you can do some nice work on the file, then load it into Excel.

Or, you know, research for how to change the default of 8 lines per column analysis by Excel. I did that some years back, but do not remember where I found the info. Sorry folks. It WAS, however, on a help site for some data program or another, providing help to their clients encountering this issue, that I first came across it. So anyone using SSIS can almost certainly get help directly from their help people.

Oddly, the string the poster claims is 374 characters long is nothing of the kind so... one wonders what else is wrong here. One suspects at a minimum that his data is delivered to him in columns 255 characters or less whether he knows it or not. But who knows?

For folks reading this, I am clearly writing long after the posting date, but hoping to make clear `raveeshvn` is CORRECT, that the problem is a matter of Excel's default number of rows analyzed per column before essaying the import/T2C work. It has not changed in the intervening years and one suspects will not change for many more years after this answer.